Mapbox causes crash when using DNS with HTTPS, but works without DNS
I'm using Mapbox in my React app, and everything works fine when the app is hosted without using DNS. However, when I switch to a DNS and access the site via HTTPS, the site crashes. If I remove the components related to Mapbox, the site works fine.
const MapComponent = ({ coordinates }) => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const marker = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return;

    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [3.0589, 36.7539], // Default coordinates (Algiers)
      zoom: 14,
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 10,
    });

    const bounds = [
      [-9.662499, 18.968147], // South-West
      [12.090135, 37.271875], // North-East
    ];
    map.current.setMaxBounds(bounds);

    map.current.on('load', () => {
      if (worldExcludingAlgeriaGeoJson && algeriaGeoJson) {
        map.current.addSource('world-excluding-algeria', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: worldExcludingAlgeriaGeoJson,
        });

        map.current.addLayer({
          id: 'world-excluding-algeria',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'world-excluding-algeria',
          paint: {
            'fill-color': '#514c4c',
            'fill-opacity': 1,
          },
        });

        map.current.addSource('algeria', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: algeriaGeoJson,
        });

        map.current.addLayer({
          id: 'algeria',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'algeria',
          paint: {
            'fill-color': 'transparent',
            'fill-opacity': 0.8,
          },
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (coordinates && !isNaN(coordinates[0]) && !isNaN(coordinates[1])) {
      map.current.flyTo({
        center: coordinates,
        essential: true,
        speed: 2.0,
        curve: 1.0,
      });

      if (marker.current) {
        marker.current.remove();
      }

      marker.current = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: 'red' })
        .setLngLat(coordinates)
        .addTo(map.current);
    }
  }, [coordinates]);

  return <div ref={mapContainer} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />;
};

export default MapComponent;

Everything works perfectly without DNS, but when I enable DNS and access the site via HTTPS, it crashes. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
